# False negative unpermitted parametter error. Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm uploading an image to an Amazon S3 bucket using paperclip and my console keep saying this:

```
Unpermitted parameters: img
```

but I already have 'strong parameters' on my controller;

```
def uploader_params
  params.require(:uploader).permit(:pdf,:img, :_destroy, :id)
end
```

my html form:

```
    # coding: utf-8
<%= simple_form_for @uploader, defaults: { label_html: { class: 'tituloFila' }, input_html: { class: 'contenidoFila'}},  :validate => true, :multipart => true do |f| %>
    <% if can? :update, Uploader and @current_action != 'show' %>
        <%#= f.button :submit, :value => "Guardar" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>

    <div class="filaMenu">
        <div>
            <a class="menuTabs hvr-underline-from-left activo" rel="tabs1" href="javascript:void(0)">General</a>
        </div>
    </div><!--fin filaMenu -->
    <div class="contenedorInfo interior">

        <div class="contTabsInterior">
            <div class="cont" id="tabs1">

                <div class="columnsTabs">
                    <div class="cuadroDatosInterior"> 
                        <% if !params[:processed_pdf].present? %>
                            <%= f.input :pdf, as: :file, :label => "Archivo" %>
                        <% else %>
                            <%= f.input :img, as: :file, :label => "Imágenes", :input_html => { :multiple => true} %>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

I ask if the user's coming from the pdf upload page (successfully) using a parameter; "processed_pdf", if so, it renders the file input but for 'img' which is a multiple file field and was created on my model using paperclip.

Comment: Can you add the full error message?

Comment: There's no error message, the rest is only mysql queries

Comment: can you post the html with the form?

Comment: Post the code for the controller action.

Comment: The action where this is failing is 'create', on the .save method. it is the default scaffold way.